# Will issues related to WiFi be there if Ubuntu is used in Virtualbox?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have a Realtek driver due to which I was having WiFi problems in Ubuntu.

Now if I use Ubuntu in a virtualbox in Windows, will the same problem of WiFi occur in "virtual Ubuntu"?

Answer (score 2):

There is lot of difference in using Ubuntu natively and as a Virtual Machine.

Generally, guest OS (Virtual Machines) share the internet connection of Host OS (here, Windows) via NAT or Bridge which will look like a wired connection inside the virtual machine irrespective of the connection Host OS is using (Wired/Wireless).

So, no you won't have issues related to WiFi if you use that as a Guest OS until Host OS experiences problem with WiFi or configuration of Guest OS or Virtualization client (Virtualbox/VMWare) is messed up.

But if you use external USB WiFi device and connect it to Guest OS disconnecting from Host OS, you may experience problems.